# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'cumsum'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cumsum

df["Size"] should output a new cumulative total without allowing the sum to drop below 0:

```
         Size 
0        11.0
1        18.0
2       -13.0
3        -4.0
4       -26.0
5        30.0
```

print(df["Cumulative"]) output should read:

```
       Cumulative
0        11
1        29
2        16
3        12
4         0 
5        30
```

I hoped lambda might help, but I get an error:

```
df.Size = df.Size.astype(int)
df["Cumulative"] = df.Size.apply(lambda x: x.cumsum() if x.cumsum() > 0 else 0)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'cumsum'
```

This error appears no matter what data type is entered 'str', 'float'

alternitively I started with:

```
df.Size = df.Size.astype(int)
df["Cumulative"] = df.Size.cumsum()
```

Output:

```
       Cumulative
0         11
1         29
2         16
3         12
4        -14
5         16
```

This output worked as expected but does not stop results from dropping below 0

Comment: You can't use vectorized code here, you need iteration with a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

You have to use `accumulate` from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import accumulate

def reset_cumsum(bal, val):
    return max(bal + val, 0)  # Enhanced by @Chrysophylaxs
    # return bal if (bal := bal + val) > 0 else 0

df['Cumulative'] = list(accumulate(df['Size'], func=reset_cumsum, initial=0))[1:]
print(df)

# Output
   Size  Cumulative
0  11.0        11.0
1  18.0        29.0
2 -13.0        16.0
3  -4.0        12.0
4 -26.0         0.0
5  30.0        30.0
```

---

You can use `expanding` and compute the sum at each iteration. If the sum greater than 0 return the sum else return 0:

```
>>> df['Size'].expanding().apply(lambda x: c if (c := x.sum()) > 0 else 0)
0    11.0
1    29.0
2    16.0
3    12.0
4     0.0
5    16.0
Name: Size, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Is there any chance you are aware of how to reset the count, output line 5 should be returning 30 with the original numbers. I ran it though with more test data, I'm not sure how to correct for the issue.

            Size  Cumulative
0            11        11.0
1            18        29.0
2           -13        16.0
3            -4        12.0
4           -26         0.0
5             5         0.0
6            48        39.0
7            63       102.0

Comment: To work with `[-20, 1, 2, 3, 4]` I added `initial=0` as parameter of `accumulate` to start with a balance set to 0.

Comment: Hello Corralien, what is the purpose of walrus operator in both of your solutions if I may ask?

Comment: The walrus operation avoid you to compute two time the same thing: ` x.sum() if x.sum() > 0 else 0`

Comment: @meowfinance. I have to fix something, there is a bug

Comment: @Corralien just seeing that the `inital=0` pulls error: `values (2828) does not match the length of index (2827)` actual df is significantly larger than posted.

Comment: You can avoid the walrus altogether with `max(bal + val, 0)` ;)

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs. Brilliant. I updated my answer and give you the credits. I wanted to use the morse operator so badly (for once!) that I didn't see the obvious. Many thanks!

Comment: @Corralien it appears to run as expected! Litteral hero! Output:

           Size  Cumulative
0            11          11
1            18          29
2           -13          16
3            -4          12
4           -26           0
5             5           5
6            48          53
7            63         116
8            92         208
9            86         294
10          113         407
11          117         524
12           57         581
13           55         636
14          -12         624
15          -29         595

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs great add! I'm teaching myself and attempting a project way too big for me, max is nice and easy to understand this is awesome!

Comment: All thanks goes to you @Corralien, I've been missing a feature in Pandas like `expanding`, but instead it uses the result computed for the previous window, and this is the solution! Now I'm thinking it'd be great if there was something like `pd.Series([-20, 1, 2, 3, 4]).accumulate(lambda a, b: max(a + b, 0), identity=0)` or something along those lines.